# Exporting an Object directly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to export an object directly, but I'm not getting the results I'd like;

```
const cmd = { 
    name: "testFunc",
    desc: "Test",
    execute(name, args) {
        console.log("Test ()");
    }
}

export {cmd}
```

I import it as follows;

```
    import(`./commands/${file}`).then(cmd => {
        console.log(cmd.cmd.name);
    })
```

But I would rather be able to just do cmd.name, rather than cmd.cmd.name.

Comment: The `import` function you're using is not ES6 but will most probably be specified in ES2020.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my mistake @str

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't export an object, use individual named exports instead:

```
export const name = testFunc";
export const desc = "Test";
export function execute(name, args) {
    console.log("Test ()");
}
```

Alternatively, change your import statement to use destructuring:

```
import(`./commands/${file}`).then(({cmd}) => {
    console.log(cmd.name);
})
```